# Using AES symmetric key for generating tokens

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes-gcm

I'm working on encrypting and decryption of authentication token.I'm very much new to security.

I have few questions can anyone help me

```
What is the most secure way to store AES  secretkey ?
Is there any advantage of using KeyStore file over just hardcoded string (password +  salt)?
```

It looks like in keystore I need a string (password + salt) with other attributes like alias,storetype,keypassword,storepass. But if I just create a (password + salt) it will give me same level of security

Comment: Why are you storing password and salt? It is normally hash and salt, however if you need to be able to access the actual password then you can't store it hashed.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Thanks for replying. so is it correct that I create a hash of **random password**  and then create a random salt and store both hashed password and hashed salt???Also, Please can you answer my questions